Nodejs - Sharp merged image buffer is corrupted
My use cases requires me to merge two image buffers and upload it to s3 signed url in every api call.
FLow:
const image1 = getImage() // from remote server (base64 encoded)
const image2 = getImage() // from remote server (base64 encoded)
const buffer1 = Buffer.from(poaFrontImage, "base64");
const buffer2 = Buffer.from(poaBackImage, "base64");
const combineBuffer = await this.mergeImagesVertically(buffer1, buffer2);
const bufferData = await combineBuffer.toBuffer();
await fs.writeFileSync('check.png', bufferData);  // this file is not opening

//further send buffer data for s3 upload.

utility function:
public async mergeImagesVertically(buffer1: Buffer, buffer2: Buffer) {
        const image1 = sharp(buffer1);
        const metadata1 = await image1.metadata();

        const mergedImage = sharp({
            create: {
                width: metadata1.width,
                height: metadata1.height * 2, 
                channels: 4,
                background: 'white',
            }
        });

        // Await the composite method to make sure it's executed before moving forward
        await mergedImage.composite([
            { input: buffer1, top: 0, left: 0 },
            { input: buffer2, top: metadata1.height, left: 0 }
        ]);

        await mergedImage.toFile('combineImage3.png'); // this image is perfect
        return mergedImage;
        //return await mergedImage.toBuffer();

    }

Every time I am trying the bufferData is a corrupted file. Is my method wrong? Please also let me know if there is a more efficient method as this functionality will be used often in every api request.

The issue with the corrupted file may be related to how you're handling the buffer data. Instead of using fs.writeFileSync, which writes the file synchronously and may not handle asynchronous operations properly, you should use asynchronous file writing methods. Additionally, you can directly return the buffer from mergeImagesVertically function instead of the sharp object.
Here's how you can modify your code:
const image1 = getImage(); // from remote server (base64 encoded)
const image2 = getImage(); // from remote server (base64 encoded)
const buffer1 = Buffer.from(image1, "base64");
const buffer2 = Buffer.from(image2, "base64");
const combinedBuffer = await this.mergeImagesVertically(buffer1, buffer2);

// Further processing with combinedBuffer (e.g., upload to S3)

// Utility function
public async mergeImagesVertically(buffer1: Buffer, buffer2: Buffer) {
const image1 = sharp(buffer1);
const metadata1 = await image1.metadata();

const mergedImage = sharp({
    create: {
        width: metadata1.width,
        height: metadata1.height * 2, 
        channels: 4,
        background: 'white',
    }
});

await mergedImage.composite([
    { input: buffer1, top: 0, left: 0 },
    { input: buffer2, top: metadata1.height, left: 0 }
]);

// Convert the merged image to buffer directly
const bufferData = await mergedImage.toBuffer();
return bufferData;
}

By returning the buffer directly from mergeImagesVertically function and handling the file writing asynchronously, you should be able to avoid corruption issues with the file. This method should also be efficient for handling your use case.

It still coming as corrupted using sharp.
I have switched to join-images package which is using sharp internally. It is working fine now. https://www.npmjs.com/package/join-images
Thanks for the response
